# Activity.getColor() not working where Application.getColor() works on a Library defined Color

Tags: android, android-activity, colors, libraries, android-resources

I'm trying to use Afollestad's Material Dialog Library in Android.  When creating the Builder I'm getting a NPE being thrown internally as it initializes colors.  I've tracked it down to simply calling "getColor()" on the passed in Activity Context and a color value from the Material Dialog Library.  If I use the Application Context, getting the value works, but then I get other failures related to presenting a dialog with an Application Context rather than Activity.

Gradle File:

```
...
dependencies {
    // APP COMPAT
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    // MATERIAL
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.1.0'
}
...
```

Pertinent Java Code:

```
// FAILING CODE
int material = activityContext.getColor(com.afollestad.materialdialogs.R.color.md_material_blue_600);

// SUCCEEDING CODE
int material = applicationContext.getColor(com.afollestad.materialdialogs.R.color.md_material_blue_600);
```

My Activities inherit from "AppCompatActivity" and my Application's base theme inherits from "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light".

Pertinent Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:87)
android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:81)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:555)
android.content.Context.getColor(Context.java:441)
```

Thank you for any insights.

Comment: `activityContext` is not set up properly. For example, perhaps you are calling `getColor()` from a field initializer, before the activity has been called with `onCreate()`.

Comment: This is happening from a button click off of the activity (dialog presented from the button).  The Activity is fully initialized at this time.

Comment: Not according to that stack trace, it is not. Perhaps `activityContext` is not pointing to the object that you think it does.

Comment: Interesting...  looks like you might be right.  My Dagger setup might be off as to who @Provides what.  Thanks